# Non-installed database

Tags: database, installation, portable-database

I need a database for my application. However, I want a portable database like SQL Express that user does not need to install any database.

However my environment is now changed to Linux. Any suggestions?

I accept both SQL (Oracle, SQL Server, Postgre...) and non-SQL (mongodb...etc) databases. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is the *de facto* standard.

> SQLite is a software library that implements a self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine. SQLite is the most widely depl

Comment: Oh look, 3 answers within <1 minute, all suggesting SQLite. Take that as a hint

Answer (score 1):

A leading server-less SQL Database is [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).

To determine when to use SQLite vs another DB, visit [this link](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/). C written and embeddable